# Django. How to change a block title in admin?

Tags: django, django-models

How do you change your models to show a necessary box-title in admin? 
[image: My admin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be changed in the following manner:

In `employees/apps.py` add:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class EmployeesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'employees'
    verbose_name = "The Title"
```

Then then in `employees/__init__.py` add the following:

```
default_app_config = 'employees.apps.EmployeesConfig'
```